# How to jump to tags in current file?

Tags: emacs

I am switching from vim to emacs. And trying to find a way to jump to tag in current java file just as vim does. For example, i have two classes both have a method called `foo`, but when i `find-tag  foo` in class `B`, it may jump to `foo` method in class `A`.